# using symbols from a namespace in one function but not another in the same file

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I have to define two functions, say, `foo()` and `bar()` in the same `namespace` and the same file. For the definition of the first, `foo()`, I want to use all symbols of, say, `namespace other`, but don't want symbols from `namespace other` to be automatically in scope for my other function, `bar()`. Is this possible? How?

(note: I don't want to know about alternative "solutions" either avoiding this problem of mitigating it, such as `namespace o=other` etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
void foo()
{
  using namespace abc;
  ....
}
```

or

```
void foo()
{
  using abc::x;
  using abc::y;
  using abc::z;
  ....
}
```

Comment: @Yakk I thought for a moment I had misunderstood the question. So I deleted and read it again.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
void quux() { std::cout << "root\n"; }

namespace other {
  void quux(int x = 0) { std::cout << "other\n"; }
}
namespace taxes {
  void foo() {
    using namespace other;
    quux(3);
  };

  void bar() {
    quux();
  }
}

int main() {
  taxes::foo();
  taxes::bar();
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/jSYEa5)

Note that `quux` in `bar` would be ambiguous if it could see `other::quux`, but it cannot.

On the other hand, this does **not** give you access to `namespace other` in the 'head' of the function `foo` (the parameters etc), but that is a rare requirement.  There might be a solution involving inline `namespace`s or the like, but probably not worth the confusion.